# como centralizar verticalmente uma tag <h2> dentro da div

Tags: css, css3, css-font-face

Gostaria de deixar o texto que esta dentro desses `<h2>` centralizado verticalmente

```
<div class="col-md-2 buttom-area">
  <div class="text-center button-disciplina button-border">
    <h2>Realizar Chamada</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center button-disciplina button-border">
    <h2>Realizar Chamada</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center button-disciplina button-border">
    <h2>Realizar Chamada</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center button-disciplina a">
    <h2>Realizar Chamada</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tentei usar o `vertical align` mas não consegui. como deixar cada `h2` dentro dessas `div` centralizados verticalmente nelas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No elemento pai use `display: table` e no elemento filho use `display: table-cell`. Assim o `vertical-align: middle` irá funcionar.

```css
.button-disciplina{
  width: 80%;
  height: 150px;
  display: table;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

h2{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-2 buttom-area">
  <div class="text-center button-disciplina button-border">
    <h2>Realizar Chamada</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center button-disciplina button-border">
    <h2>Realizar Chamada</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center button-disciplina button-border">
    <h2>Realizar Chamada</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center button-disciplina a">
    <h2>Realizar Chamada</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No caso vc queria este resultado:

```css
h2{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2 buttom-area">
  <div class="text-center button-disciplina button-border">
    <h2>Realizar Chamada</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center button-disciplina button-border">
    <h2>Realizar Chamada</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center button-disciplina button-border">
    <h2>Realizar Chamada</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center button-disciplina a">
    <h2>Realizar Chamada</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A classe `text-center` já faz isso, porém alinha horizontalmente. O OP quer alinhar verticalmente.

Comment: exatamente Phiter. Ela realiza o alinhamento horizontal. mas vertical ainda nao funciona

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `transform` como sugerido pelo nosso colega [hugocsl](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/287586/37603), porém o alinhamento usando `transform` é considerado um "hack" do css, pois não é exatamente pra isso que ele serve, apesar de funcionar.

Um approach mais moderno é usando flexbox. Você pode usar ele pra alinhar vertical/horizontalmente os elementos, assim;

```css
.button-disciplina {
  background-color: #0fc0fc;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.text-center-hv {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="col-md-2 buttom-area">
  <div class="text-center-hv button-disciplina button-border">
    <h2>Realizar Chamada</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center-hv button-disciplina button-border">
    <h2>Realizar Chamada</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center-hv button-disciplina button-border">
    <h2>Realizar Chamada</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center-hv button-disciplina a">
    <h2>Realizar Chamada</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Lembrando que se você estiver usando o Bootstrap 4, ele já possui as classes utilitárias `align-items-center` e `justify-content-center`, que podem ser utilizadas em conjunto com `d-flex` para ter o mesmo efeito.

Comment: Ao meu ver mudar o tipo de display original do elemento, que no caso da div é block para flex, apenas para faz um alinhamento seria muito mais "hake" e deselegante, do que usar  transform:translate que é justamente para ajustar as coordenas X e Y do elemento.... Mas cada um com seu ponto de vista. O legal do CSS é que da pra fazer um coisa de várias formas []´s

Comment: A propósito, quando executa o seu Snippet em "Página toda" ele não parece alinhado, nem vertical nem horizontalmente, depois olha ai. tmj

Comment: Entendi. O alinhamento horizontal está apenas no texto dentro dos quadros, e não nos próprios quadros. O rapaz pediu pra alinhar apenas o texto dentro dos quadros mesmo.

Comment: Com relação ao `translate()`, sua funcionalidade é de reposicionar um elemento no plano 2d onde ele se encontra, porém dá pra usar essa função pra mudar o "ponto âncora" do elemento (tipo no photoshop) usando as porcentagens. Realmente, tem várias formas de fazer.